# Easier Way to Display of Commutation Lemma for Limit Operator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, soft-question, education

By definition, the limit operator $\mathbb{L}$ in sequences with real terms $\{a_n\}$ commutes.

For example,

$$\color{red}{\lim_n} \color{blue}{\ln n} =  \color{blue}{\ln} \color{red}{\lim_n n} \tag 1$$

$$\color{red}{\lim_n} \color{teal}{\sqrt n} =  \sqrt{\color{red}{\color{blue}{\lim_n n}}} \tag 2$$

I know that when $f$ is continuous in $c\in (a,b)\subseteq \Bbb R$, ($\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=f(c)=f(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c} x)$), $f$ and the limit easily commute.

> But if I have not introduced the concept of continuity, how can I make it clear that the limit operator commutes, in an appropriate way, with other operators (see logarithm, $n-$th root, etc.)? Is it possible to give this as a postulate, or is it possible to create a simple proof?

I am looking for easier way to show the limit operator commute to fifth-year scientific high school students aged $17-18$.

Comment: I would try to go for a graphical approach. Drawing graphs and explaining that if you "don't have to lift the pen to draw it" it works. Maybe with a follow-up with $f(x)=1/x$, where it does not work in $x=0$, but everywhere else.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Very kind user excuse for my sincerity but I have not understood your comment. Please can you extend your comment as an answer?

Comment: At least some amount of attention to continuity (whether formalized or via "intuition") is needed to characterize when this holds. Note e.g. that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(\pi n)$ exists while "$\sin(\lim_{n \to \infty} \pi n)$" is meaningless. A starting point might be "if both limits exist, the expressions are likely to be equal, but there are exceptions." Hard to be both accurate and "easy" with this stuff.

Comment: @Sebastiano In this case the identity $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\ln n) = {\ln}(\lim_{n\to \infty} n) $ could be confusing since while for the LHS we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\ln n) =\infty$ but for the RHS we would have ${\ln}(\infty)$. Why do you want introduce this concept by an operator?

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you very much vey kind user. If is it possible can you make an simple answer with some explanation?I have understood and I am happy to upvoted.

Comment: @user Hi very kind user :-). Just to make it clear that the limit sign for the exercises we discuss can go in or out of the actual variable quantity. Simply I would like to add something practical and not totally abstract. Thanks for any response and thank you again.

Comment: @Sebastiano Maybe you could restrict the discussion to the finite case$$ \color{red}{\lim_n} \color{blue}{\ln a_n} =  \color{blue}{\ln} \color{red}{\lim_n a_n}$$ for $a_n \to L>0$.

Comment: @user Any answers that are supplemental to my knowledge and that will expand my students' knowledge are welcome.

Comment: @Sebastiano For the continuity concept I think that the suggestion given by Severin Schraven could be a good start for an intuition, using the similarity by drawing a graph for the continuous function keeping the pen always in contact with the paper.

Comment: I am not sure I can write a good answer. This is a classic case where I blackboard is great :) You could start by saying what you don't want, namely jumps (e.g.  sign function) or "infinite oscillation" ($cos(1/x)$). We note that we cannot draw any of those without lifting our pen.

Comment: Then you can pick a sequence on the domain of definition of your function (draw some points on the $x$-axis of your graph), they get mapped to (draw the corresponding points on the graph). Now let us see how the images behave (draw the points on the $y$-axis).

Comment: Then you could discuss with them what they observe (they accumulate at image of the limit point of the original sequence). You might want to discuss a bit why that happens. Being able to draw it means that if you go a tiny bit to the right with your pen, you will just displace the pen also just a tiny bit in the $y$-direction. Hence if you have the points of the original sequence accumulate around $x_\infty$, then the image of the sequence will accumulate around $f(x_\infty)$.

Comment: Also you might want to tell them that this concept is called continuity and can be appropriately formalized.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Hi very kind. Here are the 1:00 am. I like your comments + 1 for all. Peraphs is it better to use $f(a_{\infty})$ instead of $f(x_\infty)$. Please can you delete your comment and to trasform it in a nice answer with some graphs? I vote up surely :-))))))) I suggest for the drawing: https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: @user Hi, every answer for me it is always **welcome**.

Comment: Honestly I am not particularly good in drawing those things (otherwise I would have done it directly as an answer). But maybe you are more of an expert and you could write an answer yourself. I would prefer a good answer by you over a answer of me with shitty pictures.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I also think you should convert your good comments in an answer. Bye