# How to solve $\lim _{x\to \infty}\dfrac{x^5}{2^x} $ without L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Considering that asymptotically, $2^x$ grows faster than $x^5$ (in the beginning, $x^5$ grows faster than $2^x$, but there will be a point where $2^x$ outgrows $x^5$) then $\dfrac{x^5}{2^x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore,
$$\lim _{x\to \infty}\dfrac{x^5}{2^x}  = 0$$

But in order to solve the limit, I applied  L'Hospital's Rule five times

\begin{align}
\lim _{x\to \infty}\dfrac{x^5}{2^x}  & =\lim _{x\to \infty}\dfrac{5x^4}{2^x\ln 2}\\
& = \lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{20x^3}{\ln^2(2)\cdot 2^x} \\
& = \lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{60x^2}{\ln^3(2)\cdot 2^x} \\
& = \lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{120x}{\ln^4(2)\cdot 2^x}  \\
& = \lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{120}{\ln^5(2)\cdot 2^x}   \\
& = \frac{120}{\ln^5(2)}\cdot\lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^x} \\
& = 0
\end{align}

What would be a more elegant way solve it without using L'Hospital's Rule?

**Edit**

Even though, the [Limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^5}{3^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571852/limit-lim-n-to-infty-fracn53n?noredirect=1) is similar, I found the link provided by Axion004,  [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial/55477#55477) more interesting. Also, the answer provided by user trancelocation was very interesting and is what I was expecting.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/55477/258202) is the easiest way to see this. Your question is an abstract duplicate of that question.

Comment: There are many similar to your question. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571852/limit-lim-n-to-infty-fracn53n?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Axion004 Thank you, this link is really useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the series expansion $e^t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}$ as follows:

For $x>0$ you have
$$\frac{x^5}{2^x}= \frac{x^5}{e^{x\ln 2}}< \frac{x^5}{\frac{(x\ln 2)^6}{6!}}= \frac{6!}{\ln^6 2}\cdot \frac 1x$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint :**

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^5}{2^x} &= \exp \left(5 \ln(x)-x \ln(2)\right) \\
&= \exp \left[x\left(5 \frac{\ln(x)}{x}-\ln(2) \right)\right]
\end{align*}

Now, you have the very classical limit (which can be proved with elementary method) $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} = 0$$

so $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}  \left(5 \frac{\ln(x)}{x}-\ln(2) \right) = -\ln(2)$$

so $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}  \left[x\left(5 \frac{\ln(x)}{x}-\ln(2) \right)\right] = -\infty$$

and you are done.

Comment: But then how do you show $5 \ln(x) - x \ln(2) \to - \infty$ without converting back to $x^5/2^x$?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you for the answer, but could you explain a bit further? I found intuitive that $\dfrac{x^5}{2^x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but I also would like to show, write down the process to get the solution. I am not sure how the hint would help.

Comment: @user56202 I edited my answer.

Comment: The inner limit is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\left(5\frac{\log(x)}{x}-\log(2)\right)\right)$.  While $\log(x)/x\to 0$, $x\log(x)/x\to\infty$.  Your argument is therefore flawed.

Comment: @MarkViola Don't you think it's true that if $f(x) \to \infty$, $g(x) \to L \in \mathbb{R} - \{0 \}$, then $f(x) \cdot g(x) \to \text{sgn}(L) \cdot \infty$?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you for the update.

Comment: @MarkViola No, it is not, see the explanation by user56202.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That explains nothing about your lack of rigor herein.

Comment: @user56202 Yes.  And what is your point?

Comment: @MarkViola Please don't call a "lack of rigor" anything you don't understand. Just apply user56202's comment with $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=5\frac{\ln(x)}{x}-\ln(2)$ and you will see that the argument is not flawed.

Comment: @MarkViola In this answer, $f(x) = x$ and $\displaystyle g(x) = 5 \frac {\ln(x)}{x} - \ln(2)$. $f(x) \to +\infty$ and $g(x) \to - \ln(2) < 0$, so $f(x)g(x) \to - \infty$, so $e^{f(x)g(x)} \to 0$. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Stand down!  It appears you've made some edits.   And now your solution is fine.

Comment: @user56202. No.

Comment: @MarkViola All the edits had been made before your comments... But nevermind, if the solution is fine for everyone, then there is no need to continue the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative way, by ratio test

$$\frac{\dfrac{(n+1)^5}{2^{n+1}}}{\dfrac{n^5}{2^n}}=\frac12\left(1+\frac1n\right)^5 \to \frac12 \implies \dfrac{n^5}{2^n} \to 0$$

and since $\forall x>0\quad \exists n$ such that $n\le x\le n+1$ we have

$$\dfrac{x^5}{2^x}\le \dfrac{(n+1)^5}{2^{n}}=2 \dfrac{(n+1)^5}{2^{n+1}} \to 0$$

Comment: (+1) Nicely done

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks Mark! Nice to see you here around. Bye

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=5u$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x^5\over2^x}=5^5\left(\lim_{u\to\infty}{u\over2^u}\right)^5$$

so it suffices to compute $\lim_{u\to\infty}u/2^u$.  Let's do this using an inequality starting with the binomial theorem:

$$2^n=(1+1)^n=1+{n\choose1}+{n\choose2}+\cdots+1\gt{n\choose2}={n(n-1)\over2}\ge{n^2\over4}$$

for integers $n\ge2$. It follows that

$$0\le{u\over2^u}\le{\lceil u\rceil\over2^{\lfloor u\rfloor}}\le{\lfloor u\rfloor+1\over\lfloor u\rfloor^2/4}=4\left({1\over\lfloor u\rfloor}+{1\over\lfloor u\rfloor^2}\right)\to0$$

so by the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{u\to\infty}u/2^u=0$.

Comment: Hi, but isn't there a missing $5^5$ out of the limit sign?

Comment: @Sebastiano, ah yes, you're right. I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind I had voted with the assurance that you had written a very good answer.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

All we need is to know that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^t}{t}=\infty \tag{1}
$$

Let's prove that, for every $a>1$ and $b>0$ (not necessarily an integer), we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^b}{a^x}=0 \tag{2}
$$
First of all, perform the substitution $x=by$, so $a^x=(a^y)^b$ and our limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}b^b\Bigl(\frac{y}{a^y}\Bigr)^{b} \tag{3}
$$
OK, if we can prove that the limit of the part in parentheses is $0$, we're done. It's quite similar to $(1)$, isn't it? Since $a^y=e^{y\log a}$, we can perform a further substitution $y\log a=z$ and we get
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{a^y}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log a}\frac{z}{e^z} \tag{4}
$$
which is indeed $0$ because of $(1)$. The assumption that $a>1$ has been used here, because in this case $\log a>0$.

Should we prove $(1)$? You find several proofs that don’t use l’Hôpital. Perhaps the simplest is to use the mean value theorem to prove that, for $t>0$, it holds that
$$
e^t>1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}
$$

Comment: Hi very kind. Just for my recent question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259505/easier-way-to-display-of-commutation-lemma-for-limit-operator have you a possibility to give me a simplest answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$x^5$ and $2^x$ are both increasing monotonically, this is important because it guarantees there's no "weird" behavior at any subset of the real line. At the same time, as you've noticed, $(2^x)'>(x^5)'$. This analysis guarantees the limit. Of course, to be rigorous about it, you'd have to prove both claims made here, so the L'hopital's rule solution might be the easiest method.

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: @MarkViola It is a more elegant way to prove the limit of interest.

Comment: It proved nothing of the kind.

Comment: @MarkViola I agree. I just explained *how* it could be proved without l'hôpital.

Comment: If, for large enough $x>0, x^5<2^x,$ why is it important that $x^5$ is monotonically increasing? At the very best, this should've been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1369792/258202) it is shown without using L'Hopital's rule that for every $n>0$,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x}=0. \tag{1}$$

We can use $(1)$ to show that for any $n>0$ and $a > 1$,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{a^x}=0. \tag{2}$$

To do this, write $a^x = e^{(\log a)x}$ where $\log a$ is positive since $a>1$. Then, if we set $y=(\log a)x$,

$$\frac{x^n}{a^x}=\frac{x^n}{e^{(\log a)x}}=\frac{1}{(\log a)^n}\frac{y^n}{e^y}.$$

When $x\to\infty$, we know that $y\to\infty$ because $\log a >0$. Therefore the behavior of $x^n/a^x$ follows from that of $y^n/e^y$ which is zero by $(1)$. Hence your limit is zero as it is a special case of $(2)$ where $n=5$ and $a=2$.